# No Angular Animations on the default state

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, typescript

Hi here is my updated [code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-slider-button-ln8utt) which has animations of sliding left and right. So I wanted to see if we can control the default state without any animations. Like there shouldn't be any animation when panel is 'TRUE' and when we click the button the animations should work as usual.

I am now able to control the default state of the slider but the button needs to be still looked into.

Also, I have added the same code for the button too. And it won't work for the button. If we use the commented code for the button it works but again there is animation on the first time which I don't want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok! so here it is, found a solution to control the button state as well on the page load.

```
isOpenEver = false;

  get openCloseState(): string|undefined{
    if(!this.isOpenEver){
      return undefined;
    }
    return this.isOpen ? 'open' : 'closed';
  }

togglePanel(): void {
    this.isOpenEver = true;
    this.isOpen = !this.isOpen;
  }
```

And using the state in the HTML button:

```
<button [class.button-resize-expand]="!isOpen"
          [class.button-resize-collapse]="isOpen"
          (click)="togglePanel()" [@openClose] ="openCloseState">
    <mat-icon class="rotate-chevron" [class.rotate-clicked]="!isOpen">{{isOpen ? 'chevron_left' : 'chevron_right'}}</mat-icon>
  </button>
```

Also here is the updated [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-slider-button-ln8utt)

Answer (score 0):

You can disable animations with `[@.disabled]="true"`
Source: https://angular.io/api/animations/trigger#disabling-animations

Sample:

```
<div class="container" [@slide]="isOpen ? true : false" [@.disabled]="true">
```

Will disable the sliding animation of the gray box.

Comment: Hi @Stefan, thank you so much for your response. My intention is to animate the panel and button together. But on the first load they should be visible without any slide animations. As of now the panel doesn't slide on the first load, but the button does. So I am trying to control the state of button on the page load too.